# A deeper look in Bitonic array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I was trying to solve few problems, where I came across 4 types of terminologies and I think that these 4 are same and just variations.

1. First ascending and then descending :
   ex : array of integers which is initially increasing and then decreasing

   ```
   arr[] = {8, 10, 20, 80, 100, 200, 400, 500, 3, 2, 1}
   ```
2. Cyclically sorted :if we can cyclically shift the arrays to make it sorted.

   ```
   a=[37,47,55,63,10,20,22,23,27,36]
   ```

   If we do cyclically left shift by 4, it will be sorted
3. Sorted and rotated:

   An array is sorted and rotated for unknown number of times , we can say it as soorted and rotated.
4. Bitonic array:

   If an array consists of increasing sequence followed by a decreasing sequence, it is a bitonic array.

So, all these 4 are not same?
If not same, how do they differ?

p.s : In all these, a common question is to search an element/maximum/minimum.

Comment: Can you cyclically shift {8,10,20,3,2,1} to make it sorted?

Comment: 1 is same with 4. 2 is same with 3

Comment: @mangusta why 2 is 3? What is your definition for rotated?

Comment: because cyclically shift an rotate are same thing